# GeoScript: CQL DWITHIN ignoring units

Tags: geospatial, geotools

I am using GeoScript to do queries against a data set. Given an elevation tile we create geometry that incases areas that are over a certain height, those geometries are used to do some pathfinding. I am doing a DWITHIN call to get all the geometry within a range but DWITHIN is ignoring my unit type. These two calls give back the same data set (124 geometries out of 132). The axis flip is on purpose, silly APIs.

```
DWITHIN(geom, POINT(42.4979 -122.7668), 233.7, meters)

DWITHIN(geom, POINT(42.4979 -122.7668), 233.7, kilometers)
```

I have looked through the source for GeoScript and I found that the string is being sent to

```
org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL
```

The filter that is returned contains the correct unit measurement but doesn't seem to use it at all and if I print the filter out its toString also ignores the units. Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The GeoTools dwithin filter always works in the units of the underlying data. So in your case you need to specify distance in degrees or reproject your data in to a projection that is in meters.